on my React app localhost:3000 I'm getting "Index of/" with a list of my folders instead of the api data
I am new to web development. I am attempting to create a Express/Node + React Project. I've followed a tutorial and on my localhost:3000 I'm getting "Index of/" with a list of my folders instead of the api data.
Please help.
I've tried googling for help but I'm not finding any answers.

Hope you're fine.
Can you provide me the screenshot on localhost:3000 so i can see what's displaying on the browser?
However, there is always been a common issue that every developer faces which is not configuring the project properly so I've provided you the link regarding how to configure Node.js with React app project? which provided a brief overview of this topic.

This is a comment rather than an answer. Please, use answer when you declare a solution to the problem.

That's usually a problem if you're running live preview or if localhost:3000 is already in use, such as running another process. See if 3000 ports are empty and if not, consider restarting IDE or restarting PC etc.
